# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(t)|dt<\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a Borel function such that $\int_{-n}^n|f(t)|dt<\infty$ for each $n$. Suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^nf(t)g(t)dt$ exists for each bounded Borel function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(t)|dt<\infty$.

Do I need to consider a specific $g$ here so that $fg=|f|$? If so, what $g$ works?

Comment: What about $g(t)=\operatorname{sgn}(f(t))$, where $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=|x|/x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $1$ if $x=0$? Then you should use monotone convergence.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro note that the function is complex values, but yes, the idea is the same.

Comment: @b00nheT You are right. I'll leave it to the op to find a nice formula in the complex case (Hint: $|x|^2=xx^*$)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$fg=|f|\iff g=\frac{|f|}{f}$$
(Extended, for example, by zero where $f=0$)
Is $g$ Borel? Bounded?